# An ID (auto increment integer) always as primary key for each db-table?

Tags: databases

Till now, I always gave each db-table an id-column (generally with the table name and an underscore as a prefix, e.g. employee_id), and I also **never** have seen another approach to unique a db-table-record **in practice**. But on the other hand during my studies, I often have seen other columns that act as a primary key, for instance: an email/url as priamary key for a table user/photo.

At the moment I'm designing a database that contains a table first_name (because a human can have more than one first name). 
The scheme of this table first_name:{[first_name_id:integer,first_name:string]}. 
But to avoid duplicate, I would like to use the first_name as a primary key. And I also have a table employee with the column email address that also can be used as a primary key, becuase its unique.

My loss is that I dont know if I should use this approach, becuase its uncommon in practice and maybe it will cause any trouble during the programming part. So my questions is:
An ID (auto increment integer) always as primary key for each db-table?

Comment: This seems to be essentially a coding question: how should I implement this database. Coding questions are off-topic, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using RDBS.As far as you can set any value as primary key this will not cause strict programming trouble - but will be cumbersome.

What about convention that people use integer?
This comes from two parts:
It is easier to give unique id from autoincremented value.
Second is from relations and optimizations - database internally connects related items, so setting something different will cause overhead.

You should read two pages:
[normal forms in database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [primary keys](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/01/surrogate-keys-vs-natural-keys-for-primary-key/).

Normal form is something you should have (at least third level) in your database, it saves programming trouble later like with splitting keys manually.

Comment: Indeed *cumbersome* is a point that I noticed, but that  the id as an optimization purpose is new for me. Thank you!